# Setting position of an element top right inside a parent element

Tags: html, css

My HTML is like this

```
<div id="Silder">
  <span id="Open">+</span>
</div>
```

My CSS is

```
#Silder{
   height:auto;
   width:200px;
   background-color: gray;
   position: absolute;
   top:2px;
   left:2px;
   opacity: 0.5
}
#Open{
   text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000;
   top:0px;
   right: 0px;
   position: fixed
}
```

If I use the above code #Open is being set at the top right of the page. But I want this to be at Right top position Inside slider. How can I do that.. Please help me.

Comment: remove the position attribute from your #Open

Comment: @PankajUpadhyay he needs the `position` attribute otherwise the `top` and `right` attributes will be meaningless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Span is like paragraph.

Follow this link: http://jsfiddle.net/RAgf9/

All you need is : text-align: right on the container.

Comment: My requirement is close button should be always at the top of the DIV.. Like lightbox close button